# Word leftshift in table cell using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td> word1 word2 word3 word4 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this above table cell how do I perform left-shift operation on `word2`?

1. For 1 leftshift it should be like: `word1 word3 word2 word4`
2. For 2 leftshifts it should be like: `word1 word3 word4 word2`

Comment: Can you post a HTML snippet? That makes it easier to understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to shift words in the cdata or do you want to shift table cells?

Comment: <table>
  <tr>
     <td>word1 word2 word3 word4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: This design would perhaps be better : <table> <tr> <td>word1</td><td>word2</td><td>word3</td><td>word4</td> </tr> </table>

Comment: i have added html code but it is not coming properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming your table-cell has the id `foo`:

```
function shiftSecondWord(inner, count) {
    var words = inner.split(" ");
    // Remove second word
    var secondWord = words.splice(1, 1)[0];
    // insert word again offset by count
    words.splice(count + 1, 0, secondWord);
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

To shift the content of #foo 2 to the right you would:

```
$("#foo").text(shiftSecondWord($("#foo").text(), 2)));
```